# Can Rselenium use Edge as browser?

Tags: r, microsoft-edge, rvest, rselenium

I have the following part of a script to automate some search in some webpage.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(openxlsx)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 1125L, phantomver = NULL, extraCapabilities = list(`chromeOptions` = list(binary = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe')))
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
```

Everything worked fine until last week (the web we are scraping was updated). The Firefox version we have is not compatible anymore.
Our institution (hospital) manages our computers and unfortunately we can not update the browsers (Firefox and Chrome). They have recommended us to use Microsoft Edge. The problem is that Rselenium does not seem to support Edge. I found out that it is possible to install some drivers with Python and Java for Selenium in order to use Edge as the browser.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();

System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:/path/to/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
```

Does anyone know if this could be also implemented for RSelenium?

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrapping.

Comment: FYI #2 it's "in advance" and "establish".

Comment: `The problem is that Rselenium does not seem to support Edge.` That's not true. Edge is based on Chromium, so you can use the same code as Chrome. Make sure you use the correct driver though. Selenium works because all modern browsers implement the WebDriver protocol through specific drivers. You have to install such a driver for Chrome as well. RSelenium is just a binding over Selenium, it doesn't do the actual work itself. Selenium *does* work with Edge.

Comment: To use Edge driver with Selenium 3, the [Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools) package **must** be installed. In Selenium 4, the classes in the tools are fully compatible with the built-in equivalents, so we don't need to install other tools package to use Edge driver with Selenium 4. But RSelenium uses Selenium 2, you can't directly implement `EdgeDriver` in Selenium before 4. And I don't find any package which can be used with Edge driver in Selenium 2.

Comment: Thank you very much Panagiotis Kanavos and Yu Zhou for your help.